# Is it possible to connect another hdd to laptop?

Tags: hard-drive, laptop, laptop-repair

My laptop has a second bay which fits a hdd. I can see a white slot labelled hdd not in use so I'm assuming I should be able to plug in a secondary hard drive. However I can't seem to find the appropriate cable and that's got my wondering whether its even possible or whether I'm confusing what the slot is for.

Attached image of the slot. And the hard drive I'm trying to install.

The laptop is from 2012 so pretty old.
The model is a Samsung series 5.  NP550P7C 17.3" Notebook
[image: Image of laptop slot]

[image: laptop connection][image: hard drive to be installed]

Comment: Your documentation is insufficient. Neither your additional hard drive is visible on the picture nor the area where your laptop might have a connector.
It might not be a good idea to keep manufacturer and model of this device a secret.

Comment: Updated to include model and close ups of the connector. Can this question be reopened please?

Comment: "When adding another hard drive, use the secondary harddrive case, connector, and screws that are provided with this product." ref: user manual - https://www.manualslib.com/manual/421067/Samsung-Np550p7c.html?page=85#manual

Answer (score 1):

Doing a quick search for [NP550P7C HDD Cable](https://www.google.com/search?q=NP550P7C%20HDD%20cable) gives some likely candidates:

- Newegg: [New HDD Cable For SAMSUNG NP550P5C NP550P7C Laptop Hard Drive Disk Interface Connector](https://www.newegg.com/p/2S7-01PM-01MZ8)
- Ali Express: [New HDD Cable For SAMSUNG NP550P5C NP550P7C Laptop Hard Drive Disk Interface Connector](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/32906621632.html)

Similarly a search for [NP550P7C HDD cradle](https://www.google.com/search?q=NP550P7C%20HDD%20cradle) finds some items to fit a HDD into the DVD bay and also

- Ebay: [Samsung NP P500 P500Y HDD Hard Disk Drive Caddy Enclosure with screws](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Samsung-NP-P500-P500Y-HDD-Hard-Disk-Drive-Caddy-Enclosure-with-screws/331384058313?hash=item4d280771c9:g:RkYAAOSwMKpUaTyB)

They all look like what you would expect to need.